# Replace a pattern containing an apostrophe within a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file which contains this line:

```
set stime = '0 0'
```

I need to change that to:

```
set stime = '0 4'
```

I tried these commands:

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

and

```
awk '{gsub(/pattern/,"replacement")}' file
```

but they don't work. I guess it is because of the apostrophe in the pattern. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to escape single quote `'`, you should use double quotes: `"`.

In order to update in-place you should use `sed -i`

The following code should update in-place, and escape the single quote:

```
sed -i "s/set stime = '0 0'/set stime = '0 4'/g" input_file_name
```

Comment: `"` used to escape single quote, then can't it be `sed -i "s/4/1/g filename"` ?

Comment: @Lnux That would replace every instance of `4` in the entire file with `1`, which is not what was asked for. Also, the filename shouldn't be in the quotes; there's two arguments: the pattern (in quotes so it can contain spaces and punctuation); and the filename (which might also be in quotes for the same reason).

Comment: Technically, nothing is being "escaped" here; you are just able to use single quotes because they don't accidentally end the string early. *Escaping* would be adding a \ in front of a quote, which is the only way if you need to include *both* types of quotes, e.g. `sed "s/some \"double quotes\"/some 'single quotes'/g" filename`

Comment: filename outside of "..just a typing mistake and thanks for technical clarification

Answer (score 5):

You have a few choices:

1. Use double quotes instead of single quotes for the sed or awk commands:

   ```
   sed -i "s/set stime = '0 0'/set stime = '0 4'/g" file
   ```

   or

   ```
   awk "{gsub(/set stime = '0 0'/,\"set stime = '0 4'\")}1;" file
   ```
2. Save the pattern in a shell variable and use double quotes:

   ```
   replacement="set stime = '0 4'"
   pattern="set stime = '0 0'"
   ```

   then

   ```
   sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" file
   ```

   or

   ```
   awk -vpat="$pattern" -vrep="$replacement" '{gsub(pat,rep)}1;' file
   ```
3. Don't use the entire pattern. Just find the right line and replace only what needs to be changed, avoiding the quote. For example, if you only have one occurrence of `set stime`, you can do:

   ```
   sed '/set stime/{s/0 0/0 4/}' file
   ```

   or

   ```
   awk '$1=="set" && $2=="time"{sub("0 0","0 4")}1' file
   ```